# How debug GWT 2.8.1 in Intellij IDEA 2018.2 as java code instead java script

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have headache with GWT debugging in Intellij IDEA.
GWT version is 2.8.1 and Intellij IDEA 2018.2.
My application is server side with gwt. I setted GWT configuration and when I start server and separetely GWT, debug works but as javascript debug instead java, names and values of variables uncommon and not convenient for java.

Maybe someone meeted with similar problem and could say what I can resolve it?

This my GWT Configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT 2.8 uses Super Dev Mode to run client code, and it compiles Java code to Javascript, similar to production mode, see [GWT docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) for details. So you need to use Javascript debugger to debug the code.

Comment: Oh, that's sad. Thanks u